# Position image icon in HTML not working as expected

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

[what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwd8w.png)

[this is what appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byBvE.png)

I am quite new to HTML and what I want is to have an image icon over another image to clarify more there is a banner and what I need is to have a small icon in the top right corner.

I have used this code

```
<DIV style="position: relative; top:0px; left:700px; width:200px; 
height:5px"><a href="%%ftaf_url%%"><img 
src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8c13727d67037a74/m/1/ff6a555c-612a-`4609-b5a6-3bc4231cdf86.png" border="0"></a></DIV>
```

it appears fine in content block but when i send email this icon is always appearing to be in left of screen no matter what I do. I have also used below code but this also doesn't helped.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: right;">
<img src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8c13727d67037a74/m/1/ff6a555c-
612a-4609-b5a6-3bc4231cdf86.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: try `<div style="justify-content: right; text-align: right">`

Comment: Mailing should be written in `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```html
<div style="justify-content: right; text-align: right">
<img src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8c13727d67037a74/m/1/ff6a555c-
612a-4609-b5a6-3bc4231cdf86.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: This appears on the top of the content block. I would like to have something like this which is shown in the attached picture but when sending email this icon is appearing to the extreme left of the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't worked out for me and I was also facing another issue that on forwarding this email CSS was going distorted and nothing was appearing as expected so I have opened another query which I think you can help me with please have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999153/html-code-not-working-to-click-on-specific-portion-of-an-image-to-redirect-to-a

Answer (score 0):

**Neither `flexbox` or `position` work reliably in HTML Email.** Most common way to achieve this is using `<table>`s instead of `<div>`s, creating a bunch of table rows, and aligning the content.

Not sure what your code looks like, but something like this will work:

```
<table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td style="background: url('cross-hatch-background.jpg');">
            <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        <img src="envelope.png" align="right">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        <img src="logo.png" align="center">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px;">
                        navigation
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have added the images in my question itself.. I'll test your suggestion and update on this