# HTML code not working to click on specific portion of an image to redirect to a link

Tags: html

I have an image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0whRv.png) and what I need is to redirect the text Flights, holidays awards, Discover to a different link. I have tried looking for solutions and got results to use MAP tag but they aren't working for me somehow.

As mentioned in my previous question It was originally an HTML email which was loosing it's CSS on forwarding. so I just thought of pointing specific locations on this image to a different URL.

I have used below code but now the problem is all the image itself is redirecting to same link I want several links to redirect at several places on image.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
<a href="http://www.manntravel.co.nz" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8c13727d67037a74/m/1/cefb23ad-3713-4654-a642-1e099c402134.png" alt="" usemap="#Map">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="190,126,190,149,227,149,228,132">

</map></a>
```

Comment: This really doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. But, you are using wrong coordinates..
Try this one.. and click on top-left corner..

```
<img src="http://image.S7.exacttarget.com/lib/fe8c13727d67037a74/m/1/cefb23ad-3713-4654-a642-1e099c402134.png" alt="" usemap="#Map">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area alt="" title="" href="sun.htm" shape="poly" coords="17,51,42,35,66,51,66,89,17,89">
</map>
```